# Deserialize JSON and then serialize part of it back

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I can't find anywhere what I'm looking for. Probably I don't know how to describe it correctly.

Let's say I have given JSON structure:

```
{
"important": {
    "key1": "aaaa",
    "key2": "bbbb",
    "key3": "cccc"   
},
"_meta": {
    "other": {
      "default": "a",
      "something": 1
}}}
```

I'm only interested in the `important` part.

To get `important` data:

```
string temp = File.ReadAllText(jsonPath);
data = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(temp);
var important = data["important"].Value<JObject>().ToString();
importantData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(important);
```

and it does the job. Then I make some modifications on `importantData`
and I want to save it back to the file. I've tried the following code:

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(importantData);
data["important"] = json;
string rdyJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
File.WriteAllText(jsonPath, rdyJson);
```

As a result I get:

```
{"important":"{\"key1\":\"aaaa\",\"key2\":\"bbbb\",\"key3\":\"cccc\"}","_meta":{"other":{"default":"a","something":1}}}
```

which is almost good, because it has all modifications, but also extra `\`
before every `"` in the `important` part. The other thing is that everything is in one line and I'd love to have it in a sorted and clean format as before.

I think the problem is in double serialization, but I don't know how to avoid it.

Comment: I think this is happening because you are serializing json twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the following line:

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(importantData);
data["important"] = json;
```

On the next line:

```
data["important"] = JToken.FromObject(importantData);
```

Comment: This is the essence, go to the answer by @Aaron Raff for more details.

Comment: For the format form part @Siavash is right: JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data, Formatting.Indented)

Answer (score 2):

try this :

`JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data, Formatting.Indented)`

According to Newtonsoft documentation adding `Formatting.Indented` will cause the output json string to be expanded/indented rather than escaped.

https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Formatting.htm

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to explain _how_ it solves the problem without introducing others and _why_ to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Comment: @stop-cran I thought maybe it's very obvious since this is just an overload of the method. but you're about right, i'll add some more explanation.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: @Maxim_A answered as I was typing this. That answer is essentially what was stated here.

The problem seems to be when you serialize the `importantData` and then use a string to represent the json for `data["important"]`. Instead you can actually represent the `importantData` as a JObject and then use that instead.

Here is the code that I used:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

namespace jsonDeserializeThenSerializeBackQuestion
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var temp = File.ReadAllText("test.json");
            var data = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(temp);
            var important = data["important"].Value<JObject>().ToString();
            var importantData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(important);
            importantData["key1"] = "modified";

            var json = JObject.FromObject(importantData);
            Console.WriteLine(json);
            data["important"] = json;
            var rdyJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
            Console.WriteLine(rdyJson);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the output that I got:

```
{
  "key1": "modified",
  "key2": "bbbb",
  "key3": "cccc"
}
{"important":{"key1":"modified","key2":"bbbb","key3":"cccc"},"_meta":{"other":{"default":"a","something":1}}}
```

Since the data is represented as a JObject and not a string, when you serialize it again it won't escape the double quotes. In your implementation it is setting the json key `important` to be a string, not an actual json object.

Comment: only @Maxim_A answered this question a little bit earlier than you)

Comment: @Maxim_A, that's why I added the edit at the bottom.

Comment: @Maxim_A moved to the top of my post for better visibility :)